# Setting d3.curveBundle.beta seems to have no effect

Tags: javascript, d3.js

The d3 documentation on [`d3.curveBundle()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curveBundle) provides an example of how to set [*beta*](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#curveBundle_beta):

```
var line = d3.line().curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.5));
```

However, the value of *beta* supplied seems to have no effect on the curve produced. Here is a minimal example, using *beta* = 0.0 which should produce a straight line between the two end points:

```js
// create a 300x300 svg element
var w = 300;
var h = 300;
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", w)
  .attr("height", h);

// create a line generator
var rl = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.0));

// three points used to generate the path
var line_data = [{
  x: 0,
  y: -100
}, {
  x: 100,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 0,
  y: 100
}];

// path generated from line_data
svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", rl(line_data))
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");

// three circles corresponding to the points in line_data
svg.selectAll("circle")
  .data(line_data)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .attr("cy", function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .attr("r", 2)
  .style("fill", "black")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w / 2) + "," + (h / 2) + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

This code produces the same result regardless of the value of *beta* supplied. What am I missing?

Comment: I edited the question to always use the version 4.7.1 in a Stack Snippet, which is the last version having the error. Since your code referenced the head version, the error was no longer reproducible. After filing my bug report ([*Error when setting beta in minified version of d3.curveBundle. #97*](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/97)), Mike Bostock took immediate action and fixed all modules by updating the version of uglify-js to 2.8.11. The new version 4.7.2 was released right away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Problem***

It appears that d3.min.js is broken in relation to this functionality. This problem is not present in regular un-minified d3.js (both v4.7.1 - the version in the question). So, you were doing it right, weren't missing anything, just seems to have been an error introduced through the minification process.

***Update And Resolution***

This was confirmed by Altocumulus and Gerardo Furtado (see comments below). Altocumulus dug into it and found the actual discrepancy between the minified and non-minified d3.js, [flagging the issue on github](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/97). Mike Bostock quickly sourced the error to the version of uglify-js used:

> This is an excessively aggressive optimization by UglifyJS that was
>   introduced in a recent release and seems like a bad default. I will
>   see about disabling it or downgrading UglifyJS.

Mike has since [tediously updated all modules](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/97) and put out a new release today ([release notes](https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.7.2)). For the record, that was only 7 hours from Altocumulus's flagging the issue to a new release.

***Demonstration***:

The following three snippets should have identical code (based on the above code) and only differ in relation to the d3 script source. The first one is 4.7.1 un-minified, the second 4.7.1 minified, and the third 4.7.2 minified.

D3.js non-minified v4.7.1:

```js
// create a 300x300 svg element
            var w = 300;
            var h = 300;
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            // create a line generator
            var rl = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
                .y(function(d) {return d.y;})
                .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.0));

            // three points used to generate the path
            var line_data = [{x:0,y:-100},{x:100,y:0},{x:0,y:100}];

            // path generated from line_data
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("d",rl(line_data))
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

            // three circles corresponding to the points in line_data
            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(line_data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
                .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
                .attr("r",2)
                .style("fill","black")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.js"></script>
```

And d3.js minified v4.7.1:

```js
// create a 300x300 svg element
            var w = 300;
            var h = 300;
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            // create a line generator
            var rl = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
                .y(function(d) {return d.y;})
                .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.0));

            // three points used to generate the path
            var line_data = [{x:0,y:-100},{x:100,y:0},{x:0,y:100}];

            // path generated from line_data
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("d",rl(line_data))
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

            // three circles corresponding to the points in line_data
            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(line_data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
                .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
                .attr("r",2)
                .style("fill","black")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.1/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Updated (minified) 4.7.2:

```js
// create a 300x300 svg element
            var w = 300;
            var h = 300;
            var svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", w)
                .attr("height", h);

            // create a line generator
            var rl = d3.line()
                .x(function(d) {return d.x;})
                .y(function(d) {return d.y;})
                .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.0));

            // three points used to generate the path
            var line_data = [{x:0,y:-100},{x:100,y:0},{x:0,y:100}];

            // path generated from line_data
            svg.append("path")
                .attr("d",rl(line_data))
                .style("fill", "none")
                .style("stroke", "red")
                .style("stroke-width", "2px")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");

            // three circles corresponding to the points in line_data
            svg.selectAll("circle")
                .data(line_data)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x;})
                .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y;})
                .attr("r",2)
                .style("fill","black")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (w/2) + "," + (h/2) + ")");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.7.2/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is correct, the minified version is broken! It took me completely by surprise when I started to include the non-minified version to fiddle around with this and realizied it actually worked. Meanwhile, I submitted a bug report for this: [*Error when setting beta in minified version of d3.curveBundle.*](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/issues/97). Let's see what happens...

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, it was pretty surprising for me as well.

Comment: It was surprising to me as well. When OP first posted the question, after 20 minutes scratching my head with no idea of the solution and having studied the source code (the unminified, though!), I decided to set this bounty, to see if any of you guys could solve the mystery. Good on you @Andrew Reid, upvoted.